# Increase the keywords library

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have been trying Machine Learning algorithms for text classification. It works pretty well. However, I also want to add an automatic feature of addition of new keywords in my keywords library. For example, my current library is like the following:

```
[
[food,eat,drinks],
[travel, explore, visit],
[business, work, future]
]
```

Now, I try to import a random string. For example:

```
importString = "I am Harish. I am a foodie. I do not like long journeys. I am an entrepreneur."
```

After importing the above string, I am removing all the stop words first, and then I want to automatically update my library (without human help) such as:

```
[
[food, eat, drinks, foodie],
[travel, explore, visit, journeys],
[business, work, future, entrepreneur]
]
```

Is there any way (in the field of Machine Learning or Deep Learning) to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

You could just append the word to the list.
The exact syntax for the code depends on the language you are using, but in python its:

```
list.append(stuff-to-add-to-list)
```

supposing that the name of your list is "list" and the variable to append to the list is "stuff-to-add-to-list"

Comment: Well, this is not a simple 'append' method that I am asking for. I want the machine to understand automatically which keyword should be appended to which list. As you can see in the given example, the keyword 'foodie' is automatically appended to the list related to food, and not to the list related to traveling.
I hope this clarifies you.

Comment: oh, ok in that case I've no idea how to do that.